# Float to unsigned integer in C

Tags: c, casting

Currently I am using a DHT11 sensor to measure temp and humidity in a room. The DHT sensor outputs these values as floats, however, I would like to send values as integers (24.3 degrees would be 24 for example). I'm having a hard time finding a way to do this.

The reason why I ask for an unsigned integer, is because the DHT range is from 0 to 50 degrees celcius, there is no need for a signed integer

Comment: how about [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/round)?

Comment: In the title of this question you are asking for a cast to _unsigned_ int, but a temperature, if measured in Celsius or Fahrenheit, could have a negative value.

Comment: Yes, however, the dht11 has a range from 0 to 50 degrees celcius

Comment: *"The DHT sensor outputs these values as floats..."* The DHT11 outputs 5 8-bit fields (2 for humidity, 2 for temperature, 1 for parity). Each pair comprises an integer byte and a fraction byte. All you need to do is ignore the fraction byte (or round up the integer byte if >= 0x80). What has floating point got to do with it?

Comment: there's no difference between casting from float to int or unsigned int

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
float x = 24.3 ;
unsigned int y;
y = (unsigned int) x;
```

for -ve values, `unsigned int n = static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<int>(-1.3));` can help

Comment: Why are you using _unsigned_?

Comment: That's the OP's requirement!

Comment: Try casting negative number. It gives unexpected result.

Comment: Well, that's ok for measuring humidity, but the temperature (even in a room) could be negative (in °C or F)...

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUddin You should round values correctly 24.9 => 25.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUddin Your edit is not valid in C, anyway, even if fahrenheit could be negative, the question is "Float to unsigned integer in C", seems like a correct answer to me.

Comment: @KeineLust Fair enough, that's a problem of OP's question.